# Access the child object of a unknown parent in nested json using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, json

I have a nested JSON object.

I do not know the position of the parent in the nested JSON object.

I know the property value of the parent I am trying to access.

I need to access the rows object whose index = 0 or 3 or 2 etc based on the items in an array.

If the array contains 0,3 then I would like to access the cells object of the rows object whose index property is 0 and then access the cells object of the rows object whose index property is 3.

The topmost item in the rows object may not contain the index property as 0.

I won't know the position of the rows object although I know the property's value.

Also i do not want to loop through the row collection using foreach.

I would like to know if there is a way to acheive without using loops.

I am trying to do this without loops and if not possible then i may have to consider using for loop /foreach as the last option.

```
data.rows[x].index=0
data.rows[y].index=3
```

here i do not know x and y but i know the index property value of data.rows[x] and data.rows[y]

```
var data ={
   "name":"Members",
   "rows":[
      {
         "index":3,
        "cells":[
            {
               "value":"Name",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":"ID",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":"Total",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":"Dec2019_Data",
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":"Jan2020_Data",
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":2,
         "cells":[
            {
               "value":"NewMember",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":240,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":200,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":100,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":100,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":0,
        "cells":[
            {
               "value":"Timo (718)",
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "value":150,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "value":400,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "value":300,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "value":100,
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "index":1,
         "cells":[
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":0
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":1
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":2
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":3
            },
            {
               "color":"#000000",
               "enable":false,
               "index":4
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hi i am using javascript and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to fetch the rows based on index

```
var jsonArray = [];
var rowCollection = data.rows;
var uniqRows=[0,3,2];
var ChangedRows=[];
ChangedRows= $.map(rowCollection, function(val, key) {
                                       if (uniqRows.indexOf(val.index) > -1)
                                           return val;
                                   });



ChangedRows.sort(function(a, b){
                                       return a.index-b.index
                                   })

var rowCount = uniqRows.length;

                                for (var i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++) {




                                    var objs=ChangedRows[i].cells;


                                        objs = objs.map(function (obj) {
                                            return { value: obj.value };
                                        });

                                        jsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(objs, null, 2));}
```